# SAS Date counter

Tags: date, sas

I have 2 columns Start_date and End_date for one particular individual there are multiple rows on start_date and end_date,  I want to calculate the no of days between sTART_DATE OF the SECOND row - END_DATE OF FIRST ROW.

```
Person  Start   End     
A   5/11/2019   9/11/2019   I need to get 14/11/2019-9/11/2019 =    4
A   14/11/2019  20/11/2019  Like wise   10
A   1/12/2019   10/12/2019      2
A   12/12/2019  19/12/2019      0
B   1/1/2018    5/1/2018        4
B   9/1/2018    11/1/2018       0
```

Comment: 14-9 is 5 not 4? Please post anything you've tried as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Sort depending by date so that you can use the LAG() function
2. Get the lagged start date
3. Calculate the difference

   ```
   *create sample data for testing;

   data have;
       input Person $ Start : ddmmyy10.  End  : ddmmyy10.;
       format start end date9.;
       cards;
   A   5/11/2019   9/11/2019   
   A   14/11/2019  20/11/2019  
   A   1/12/2019   10/12/2019      
   A   12/12/2019  19/12/2019      
   B   1/1/2018    5/1/2018        
   B   9/1/2018    11/1/2018   
   ;
   run;

   *sort by descending date to use LAG();

   proc sort data=have;
       by person descending start;
   run;

   data want;
       set have;
       *analyze by person;
       by person;
       *calculate the previous start date;
       lagStart=lag(Start);
       *do the calculation if not the first record for the person;

       if not first.person then
           diff=lagStart - end;
       else
           diff=.;
       format lagStart date9.;
   run;

   *sort back to desired order;

   proc sort data=want;
       by person start;
   run;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `retain` statement. The rest of the algorithm repeats @Reeza solution:

```
proc sort data=have;
    by person descending start;
run;

data want(drop=tStart);
   set have;
   by person;
   retain tStart;
   if not first.person then do;
      diff = tStart-End;  
   end;
   else do;
      diff = 0;
   end;
   tStart = Start;
run;

proc sort data=want;
    by person start;
run;
```

**Input:**

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| Person |   Start   |    End    |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| A      | 12DEC2019 | 19DEC2019 |
| A      | 01DEC2019 | 10DEC2019 |
| A      | 14NOV2019 | 20NOV2019 |
| A      | 05NOV2019 | 09NOV2019 |
| B      | 09JAN2018 | 11JAN2018 |
| B      | 01JAN2018 | 05JAN2018 |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

**Output:**

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+------+
| Person |   Start   |    End    | diff |
+--------+-----------+-----------+------+
| A      | 05NOV2019 | 09NOV2019 |    5 |
| A      | 14NOV2019 | 20NOV2019 |   11 |
| A      | 01DEC2019 | 10DEC2019 |    2 |
| A      | 12DEC2019 | 19DEC2019 |    0 |
| B      | 01JAN2018 | 05JAN2018 |    4 |
| B      | 09JAN2018 | 11JAN2018 |    0 |
+--------+-----------+-----------+------+
```